# vba duplicate and partial string match

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of product codes where I want to mark it ** at the end of the code if there is different location. 
To elaborate that, an example of the product code is PFL512241-02 where 02 is the location code. So if I get PFL512241-02 and PFL512241-03 in the list, I would like mark my result as PFL512241-02**; so smaller number of my location. If PFL512241-02 shows up 5 times, result should be PFL512241-02. If PFL512241-02 shows up one time, then I want to ignore it since I only want products that showed up more than 1 time. I am also calculating occurrence for each product.

Now my codes will only get me the product codes without ** so I need help on that part.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProductNumT()

'Set up'
Dim LR1, LR2, LR3, LR4, LR5, LR6, LR7, LR8, LR9, i, j, k, l, m, n As Long
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4, cell As Range
Dim Selection, CBA, PNT As Worksheet

Set CBA = Worksheets("Master")
Set PNT = Worksheets("ProductNumT")
Set Selection = Worksheets("Selection")

LR1 = CBA.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


'Clear values
PNT.Columns("A:J").ClearContents



'Find products
   With CBA.Range("C2", "C" & LR1)
         .AutoFilter
         .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Selection.Range("B6").Value
         .Copy
        PNT.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          .AutoFilter
    End With

 'Sort
PNT.Range("B2", "B" & LR1).Sort _
Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending



'Product w/o location
    LR2 = PNT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With PNT.Range("C2", "C" & LR2)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],9)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        For k = 2 To LR2
        PNT.Cells(k, 1).Value = 1
        Next k




'Find duplicates & extract unique values from the list

    PNT.Range("D2", "D" & LR2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(C1,C3,RC[-1])"
    PNT.Range("D2", "D" & LR2).Copy
    PNT.Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

      For i = 2 To LR2
        If PNT.Cells(i, 4).Value <= 1 Then
            PNT.Rows(i).ClearContents
          End If

   Next i

     PNT.Range("B1").ClearContents
     PNT.Range("D2", "D" & LR2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
     PNT.Range("C2", "C" & LR1).Copy
     PNT.Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     PNT.Range("E2", "E" & LR1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo



     'Main calculation
 LR4 = PNT.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        With PNT.Range("F2", "F" & LR4)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C2,MATCH(RC[-1],C3,0))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        With PNT.Range("G2", "G" & LR4)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C4,MATCH(RC[-1],C2,0))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

End Sub
```

First picture is what I have now, and second picture is my desire results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my logic and I appreciate if anyone can share a faster way to find the result column.

Comment: fyi:  n is declared as long,  cell is declared as range, PNT is declared as worksheet .... the rest of variables are declared as variant

Comment: you want to make a list of products, display quantity of each product, and you want to mark any product that has multiple locations .... is that correct?

Comment: i get the list of data from sheet Master column C and i only want to display all products that have more than 1 occurrence that's why i count number of products by setting my result sheet column A values as 1. Again, if the product PFL512241-01 shows up 5 times, my result for PFL512241 product is PFL512241-01 with occurrence of 5.

Comment: If I have PFL512241-02 showing up 3 times and PFL512241-01 shows up 2 times, my end result for PFL512241 should be PFL512241-01** and 5 as occurrence. So I want to display the "smallest" location since I already sorted the product codes in ascending order in column B.

Comment: When I say occurrence, you can treat it as transaction, so same product can be sold in New York or Seattle and I only want to display which products are sold more than quantity of 1 if that's easier to understand.

Comment: So I think what your asking is correct, I can't have a product sold in different locations but not display **. However, I can have a product sold in one city and in that case I won't need to mark ** since its the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following formula should work for column F

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C2,MATCH(RC[-1],C3,0))&IF(COUNTIF(C2,INDEX(C2,MATCH(RC[-1],C3,0)))<COUNTIF(C3,RC[-1]),""**"","""")"
```

It counts how many occurrences there are of `PFL180437-02` (for instance) in column B and, if that is less than the number of occurrences of `PFL180437` in column C (and therefore there is some other `PFL180437-xx`), it appends an `"**"`.

Comment: thanks I don't have my workbook with me but will definitely try when tomorrow morning first thing

Comment: thanks it works, you just miss )" at the very end of the codes but it works as what I need. Thank you guys.

Comment: @sc1324 Sorry about that missing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but ...

```
Dim LR1, LR2, LR3, LR4, LR5, LR6, LR7, LR8, LR9, i, j, k, l, m, n As Long
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4, cell As Range
Dim Selection, CBA, PNT As Worksheet
```

`Selection` is a VBA object. You can't have a variable by that name.

In the first line, only `n` is a Long. All the others are undefined, meaning variants. In the second line, only `cell` is a range, all others undefined and therefore variants. In the third line, only PNT is a worksheet, all others undefined and therefore variants.

Comment: I can fix that since I have a sheet named Selection.

Comment: The sheet's name "Selection" is OK. Just give the variable another name, like, `Set WsSelection = Worksheets("Selection")`. BTW why don't do you this with worksheet functions?

Comment: which part do you suggest that I should use worksheet functions? I would like to know. thanks

Comment: yes I will rename Selection as WsSelection, thank you

Comment: Actually, all of it. Your own code is simulating the user interface - not useful unless you need to do it all the time. YowE3K has provided a worksheet function for your column F. Why to use VBA to write the function? Copy/paste will do the same job, but faster.

Comment: i started using pivot table but then I thought I could try vba codes and see if it will run faster and instead of refreshing the pivot table each week when I get new data.